# From Django project achieve an asynchronous request to external API?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

In my Django project, I have to implement an asynchronous HTTP request to the external API and get the result. I found that by using Django channels and celery we can do. There is a package in the tornado simpleAsynchronousHttp package is there anything in Django. please, can anyone suggest which is the better way to achieve asynchronous HTTP call to external API and get data in Django?

Comment: You could probably create a task, where in you can perform HTTP request to external api. And you can invoke the task asynchronously using Celery. refer http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests is a python package, which makes it pretty easy to do HTTP requests. In order to do it asynchronously, you can leverage [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html). For celery setup, you can follow the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps). You can use [redis](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html) as a broker.

Create a task inside your app.

```
# proj/tasks.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app
import requests # https://github.com/requests/requests


@app.task
def call_api():
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
```

In the file wherever you want to call the function, e.g. in your views

```
# proj/views.py
from tasks import call_api
call_api.delay()
```